# Create relationships between users or user roles

Tags: users, user-roles

I have a site where doctors and patients are registered. It provides services like where patients (role-patient) are registered themselves and after my support person (role-support) assign that patients to the separate doctor (role-doctor) who registered with us already.

I explain my problem with an example. e.g. I have total 10 users. Admin,Support,doctor-1 to doctor-4(Total 4 doctors) and patient-1 to patient-4(Total 4 patients). I already mentioned in first paragraph that the doctor has role of doctor and patient has role name of patient.

If My support person assign the Patient-1 and Patient-2 to Doctor-4. Than only doctor-4 is able to see the both patients in their profile page after login. It means The doctor-4 can not see the other both patients(patient-3 and patient-4).

Is there any plugin or code for the same is available in WordPress or Buddy-Press ?

I google so much and checked so many similiar or releted to my problem pugins but only this plugin has the same feature what I want but it's so costly for me now. I used it's nulled version but it's create so many issues like it's got an error in my wp-login.php file and it's haven't mobile responsible and so many more...

Link - https://codecanyon.net/item/hospital-management-system-for-wordpress/12094634?s_rank=18

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For functionality like this I think you'll have to go with premium plugins or code it yourself.

If you want to go with custom code Pods might be able to help you out with creating relationships between doctors and patients: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/

Comment: Hi ! Jory Thanks but I already tried it but it's not suite for me. Is anything You want to suggest me ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but if you are not comfortable enough to code it yourself and can't find any premium plugins that 100% suit your needs I suggest you hide a developer that can help you with this project. Pods is a plugin that can provide the management interface for this but you still need to code the restrictions yourself. They have a job channel in their Slack workspace (https://slack.pods.io/) where you can ask developers for help.